# Swift optionals - Why does var a:Int? a? = 4 return nil

Tags: swift, option-type

Why does `print(a)` in the following code print nil?

```
var a:Int?
a? = 4
print(a)  //prints nil

var b:Int? = 4
print(b) //prints optional(4)
```

Shouldn't they both contain 4? Can someone explain it?

Comment: The problem is the expression `a? = 4` (what you meant was `a = 4`). I don't understand why it compiled in the first place; perhaps that should be as a bug.

Comment: See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6498.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line `var a: Int?` declares an optional variable with a `nil` value.

The line `a? = 4` makes use of optional chaining to assign a value to the variable `a`. But if `a` is `nil`, the assignment isn't done. And this is your case since `a` is currently `nil`. You simply need `a = 4` to assign the value of `4` to the variable `a`.

Comment: Okay, this is https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6498 - the syntax is legal (and it _is_ Optional chaining whether I like it or not) but the proposal is that this should warn, as it doesn't mean what one thinks it does

Comment: Interesting. `a? = 4` has the effect "If `a` is nil, replace it with 4. If it already has a value, leave it alone." That is counter-intuitive, but could be useful. I'd put that in the same category as `if (a = b)` in C, which is legal, and can be used constructively, but is so easy to get wrong that it shouldn't be allowed without a compiler warning.

Comment: @DuncanC Your first sentence is incorrect. You meant: `a? = 4` has the effect "if a is *not* nil, replace it with 4.

Comment: Oh yeah. I got that backwards. That's less useful. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ......... as as? is nil the entire statement won't run

```
a? = 4       ==   nil = 4
```

do

```
a = 4
```

Comment: @Daniel on Stack Overflow there is a technical category "not an answer" and I assure you, this is not in that category. We've gone over this many times on Meta. A non-answer would be "Yes, I'm having that problem too" or "Please click this link" or "Did you ever solve this?"